# Why electrons do not distribute evenly among the atoms in a molecule?

Tags: molecular-orbital-theory, energy, orbitals, atoms

I was wondering why the state where electrons are evenly (or the closest to being evenly) distributed among the atoms in a molecule is not the lowest energy state? For example, in a water molecule it is known that oxygen attracts electrons from hydrogen due to its high electronegativity (oxygen wants to fill its shell). But if we instead took 4 electrons off the oxygen outer shell and just filled hydrogen states with them we would have 2 hydrogen atoms with 1s$^2$ 2s$^1$ configuration and our oxygen with 1s$^2$ 2s$^2$ configuration. This way we eliminate supposedly high-energy p-states of oxygen and populate lower-energy s-states of hydrogen and lower the total energy.

I know that my example is extremely naive if not brutally wrong. I thought that maybe energy levels of different atom types have different energies which results in the correct electronic distribution (not like in my example above) in a water molecule to be truly the lowest energy state. Or maybe my logic violates some quantum mechanical postulate...I couldn't immediately find why my reasoning is wrong so I hope someone here would help me out.

Thank you!

Comment: What do mean by "distribute evenly"? They've distributed in a way that minimizes the energy. I'd call that pretty even.

Comment: @Zhe as I tried to suggest by my example, if you take high energy electrons from the p orbitals of oxygen and put them on energetically lower orbitals of hydrogen the total energy would be lower. "Even" means to take all the electrons available and put them on the lowest levels of all atoms in the system. My model is clearly wrong, but I believe I introduced it clearly.

Comment: Why don't the protons all distribute evenly across the atoms in the molecule?

Comment: @JonCuster I don't know how proton energy states/levels look like. If you wanted to make an analogy, could you please expand on this?

Comment: But the system _has_ accounted for the all factors and the energy-optimized system is what's observed. The primary issue may simply be that your view of the system (atomic orbitals in a molecule) is not accurate enough to produce the meaningful result you want.

Answer (score 2):

**Atomic orbitals are not the same as molecular orbitals**

You seem to be assuming that the electron orbitals of isolated atoms are the same as the orbitals that exist in stable molecules. So the issue is *which* orbitals get filled to create the lowest energy configuration.

But the quantum mechanics of orbitals is a lot more complex than that. The orbitals that exist in atoms are the possible configurations of electrons for an isolated molecule. But if you solve the relevant equations for a molecule you get *different* orbitals and they depend on the properties of *all* the nuclei in the molecule.

Getting that full solution is usually a computational nightmare and chemists tend to think and describe the solutions in terms of combinations of atomic orbitals. But those combinations need to recognise the nuclear properties of the component atoms. So an oxygen atom has more charge than a hydrogen and the molecular orbitals will show a higher electron density near oxygen (or, higher than you would get for an isolated oxygen filling its atomic orbitals).

The reason we don't get an even distribution is because the nuclei are not the same and have different charges. The stable molecular orbitals recognise this giving uneven distributions of the electron density.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Certainly the complete physics is complex, but there are simple rules like the "octet rule" that I am trying to make sense out of. The fact that atoms want to make their shell complete just isn't so clear for me, and that is why I started to think about possible states in terms of their energies.

Comment: @CHILLQQ consider that independently of the frame, just external electrons are involved in bond formation.

Comment: @CHILLQQ The octet rule is a **very** simplistic rule of thumb to explain how bonding works and it totally fails to capture anything useful about the *details* of bonding or electron distributions. It is certainly not suitable for describing anything about electron distributions in bonds, for that you need some molecular orbital theory.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer online that satisfied me.

https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Inorganic_Chemistry/Map%3A_Inorganic_Chemistry_(Miessler_Fischer_Tarr)/05%3A_Molecular_Orbitals/5.03%3A_Heteronuclear_Diatomic_Molecules

It shows that 1s orbital of Hydrogen has energy of -13.64 eV whereas 2s and 2p orbitals of oxygen have -32.36 eV and -15.87 eV respectively. This suggests that it is indeed energetically more favorable to keep oxygen electronic states occupied instead of transferring electrons to hydrogen orbitals, which are apparently higher in energy. I suggested in my question that "energy levels of different atom types have different energies " but I couldn't find the confirmation, and now I found it.

Comment: We do operate this energy distinction. And it is even not our choice. While is drastic in some approximation, it is natural. It is even not a choice. It it would be for electrons deeper in energy there won't be chemistry. Very much as when you touch a body you encounter its surface first (macroscopically, else I am afraid someone may show up with "no, touching is electron repulsion". Which albeit a bit hand waving serves to the purpose as well :)